# Can't update multiple records on tables with hasMany in CakePhp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-2.1

I have a table "Topic" that is linked to "Post" with hasMany in the model.

I can't figure out how to update the two tables at once.

This is my $this->request->data

```
Array
(
  [Topic] => Array
      (
          [id] => 1
          [topic_title] => This is my topic
      )

  [Post] => Array
      (
          [1] => Array
              (
                  [id] => 1
                  [title] => Blah
                  [message] => My message
              )

          [2] => Array
              (
                  [id] => 2
                  [title] => Second Blah
                  [message] => Second My message
              )

      )

)
```

I've tried to do like this :

```
$this->Topic->save($this->request->data);

$this->loadmodel('Post');

$this->Post->updateAll($this->request->data, array('Post.topic_id' => $id));
```

This is clearly the wrong approach however I struggling to find a good way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You should use saveAssociated

```
$this->Topic->saveAssociated($this->request->data);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `$this->Topic->save($this->request->data)` it will only try to save the [Topic] array inside your data array.

You can either use `$this->Topic->saveAssociated($this->request->data)` or `$this->Topic->saveAll($this->request->data)` for the save to apply on other arrays inside your data array. The `saveAll()` function covers both `saveAssociated()` and `saveMany()` saves, although cakePHP manual suggests using either one of these instead of the `saveAll()` function